# How to load numbers into MySQLi fetch_array() function

Tags: javascript, php, json, mysqli

Using following MySQLi and PHP snippet I can export the result in a numeric array as:

```
["8","188.396496","7.876766","69885005.45"]
```

Now I need to have the output in exact numeric format like (removing " "  from the items)

```
[8,188.396496,7.876766,69885005.45]
```

and here is the code I have in PHP part

```
$query = "SELECT project, powerline, road, cost FROM `charts_econo_new`" ;
$results = $con->query($query);
if($results) {
  while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
     $json=json_encode($row);
  }
}
$con->close();
echo $json;
?>
```

How can I do that?

### Update

```
   var req2 = $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      data: data,
                      dataType: 'json', 
                      url: "assets/tempchart.php"
                    });
   req2.done(function(data) {
                            var cars = [];
                            cars.push(data)
                            console.log(cars[0]);
```

in this case the out out is `[8,188.396496,7.876766,69885005.45]` but I need to get ONLY 8 as cars[0] is 8.

Comment: FYI, you're only echoing the last row. You overwrite `$json` each time through the loop.

Comment: Barmar, thanks for the hint, the `charts_econo_new` is actually a Temporary table to keep ONLY one row of Sums, thanks anyway

Comment: If there's only one row, why do you have a `while` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($results) {
    $row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    $row = array_map('floatval', $row); // Convert strings to numbers
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

The Javascript should be:

```
req2.done(function(data) {
    var cars = [];
    cars.push(data[0]);
    console.log(cars[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot Barmar, just can you please also let me know how I can load the result into a Javascript Array like cars=[] in in jquery ajax .done()? Thanks

Comment: If you specified `dataType: 'json'`, you can just do `cars = result`.

Comment: I did but need to create an array explicitly to reference them in highchart.js Unfortunately highcharts raising the Uncaught Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14  when I go this way so I tried to load the data into a Javascript array

Comment: in that case a car[0] (indexed value) is accepted by highchart

Comment: If `cars` is a 2-dimensional array, and this should be a new row, then use `cars.push(result)`.

Comment: Sorry Barmar, but some thing wrong happening here. What I have done is req2.done(function(data) { var cars = []; cars.push(data)  console.log(cars[0]); }); but in console log I am getting the full list of the arry

Comment: I don't have any idea how you need to use this data. Push whatever part of the result you need into `cars`.

Comment: Update the question and show what `cars` should look like after everything is done. Then I can better answer the question.

Comment: sure please give me a second

Comment: I am afraid , but how about other values? do we have to push them one by one? I mean cant we push them all togeter in the array and access them seperatly?

Comment: If you want all of them, just do `cars = data;`. It's just an array, do whatever you want with it. There's nothing complicated here. Figure out what you want the final result to be, and do it.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to cast your results to float before calling json_encode :

```
$query = "SELECT project, powerline, road, cost FROM `charts_econo_new`" ;
$results = $con->query($query);
if($results) {
  while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
     // Cast to float
     foreach($row as &$item) {
       $item = (float) $item;
     }

     $json=json_encode($row);
  }
}
$con->close();
echo $json;
```

(And you are only getting the last row of your table, because you overwrite the content of $json each time but if you only have one row in your table that can be ok)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) function to convert string from DB in float values.

Comment: may be more helpful if you actually show how to use 'floatval' in this situation?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. The other answers of this thread shows perfectly how to use that function. Thanks.

Comment: So what does your answer provide that is extra and useful to the person who asked the question?

Comment: What? Is it an exam? I'm sorry again. My english is very poor and my answer is very short (in your opinion) and not very useful. That's right. I only pretended to help, not disturb.